# moving a dataframe to redshift using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift

I have a table in redshift as

```
id, name, address
1, 'aaa', 'xxx'
2, 'bbb', 'yyy'
```

I have a dataframe in pyspark as

```
id, name, address
1, 'ccc', 'zzz'
5, 'ddd', 'xyx'
```

Now I need to upload the dataframe in pyspark to redshift table using upsert mode.

Can anyone help me in how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Redshift Data Source for Apache Spark](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) for this. Keep in mind that the tables should already exist in Redshift before you load this data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to check your intended table's presence in redshift. Then you can take the help from the following code.

```
# Write back to a table
df.write \
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://redshifthost:5439/database?user=username&password=pass") \
  .option("dbtable", "my_table_copy") \
  .option("tempdir", "s3n://path/for/temp/data") \
  .mode("error") \
  .save()
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you append your dataframe rows